# Can we change the ordering of parameters in transition shorthand property?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, css-transitions

The proper order of transition shorthand property is as

```
transition: <property> || <duration> || <timing-function> ;
```

Recently I noted that in Bootstrap they changed the order for `.carousel-inner` class as:

```
transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
```

That is as: `transition: <duration> || <timing-function> || <property>`

Infact the transition works exactly same no matter how we arrange the three parameters. So the question is,

Can we change the ordering of parameters in transition shorthand property? Does the order of parameters really matter?

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

@user31782 you had commented that perhaps the order of shorthand transitions doesn't matter unless there is both a duration and delay. Your deduction appears to be correct:

> [Just space-separate all the individual values. The order doesn't matter except when using both duration and delay, they need to be in that order.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/#article-header-id-3)

Although this is referring to animation shorthand, it is a logical assumption that this applies to transition shorthand properties as well:

1. `animation` and `transition` shorthand properties are very similar in function.
2. Bootstrap is mixing the order up and it still works.

   ---

   ### OLD

Are you sure there are no other transitions further down the cascade? Did you check the computed style?

> Note that order is important within the items in this property: the first value that can be parsed as a time is assigned to the transition-duration, and the second value that can be parsed as a time is assigned to transition-delay.

If there is more than one `<single-transition>` in the shorthand, and any of the transitions has ‘none’ as the `<single-transition-property>`, then the declaration is invalid.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-shorthand-property

Comment: No there are no further transitions in the computed style. And the transition-delay is also not mentioned. I think the order only matters if there is `transition-delay` and `duration` both used in the shorthand notation.